# Распарсить дату и сделать список диапазон дат

Tags: java

Допустим есть список такой структуры:

```
class ThisIsChelabinsk{
................
private int day;
private int month;
private int year;
................
}
```

мне необходимо с сделать список который по сути своей будет представлять из себя календарь. допустим от `1.1.2000` и до `1.1.3000`. при этом мне надо распарсить дату для того чтобы занести элементы в необходимые поля.

Также интересует вопрос как можно сделать список в списке.

например есть элемент 1 и у него есть свой список из 3х элементов. есть элемент 2 в главном списке и у него например 5 элементов.

Comment: Почему вы не используете `String.split()` для разделения по точке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

тут не один вопрос, но можно решить

---

Как распарсить дату.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Note: zero based!
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```

---

Теперь как создать цикл дат

```
try {
    Calendar gcal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d.M.yyyy");
    Date start = sdf.parse("1.1.2000");
    Date end = sdf.parse("1.1.3000");
    gcal.setTime(start);
    do {
        Date d = gcal.getTime();
        System.out.println(d);
        gcal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    } while (gcal.getTime().before(end));
} catch (ParseException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

А создать список в списке можно

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// создаем внутренный список
ArrayList<String> singleList = new ArrayList<String>();
singleList.add("hello");
singleList.add("world");

// добавляем этот список в главный
listOLists.add(singleList);

// создаем внутренный список №2
ArrayList<String> anotherList = new ArrayList<String>();
anotherList.add("this is another list");

// добавляем этот список в главный
listOLists.add(anotherList);
```

Comment: а если допустим у меня в списке 1 у каждого элемента есть свой список 2 а у каждого элемента есть список 3. списки я делаю по сути через
Struct test = new Struct();
test.add("ASDA",123,123);

Comment: @ParanoidPanda какой список нужен? Список в списке в списке? List<List<List>> - такой? если можно, создай отдельно вопрос и изложи там. Легче будет отвечать

Comment: оформил вопрос.