# Список в списке в списке

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Есть некий список - серые квадраты его элементы. Их может быть N штук. В каждом элементе этого списка может находится еще список - зеленые квадраты. Их может быть M штук, также их может не быть вообще. В каждом элементе этого списка может быть еще список - желтые квадраты. Их может быть Q штук, или может вообще не быть. 
Структуру я делаю примерно как тут: [ссылка](http://axis.bplaced.net/news/773)(из своего кода очень долго вырывать).

Также например. Мы создаем элементы (зеленые и желтые) по определенному правилу. Допустим у нас каждый элемент это отрезок у него есть точки x1 и x2. И каждый новый элемент имеет свои уникальные точки. НО! так чтобы они не входили в интервал других отрезков и не были равны. 
Например:

```
s1.x1 = 2;
s1.x2 = 5;
s2.x1 = 6;
s2.x2 = 7; 
верно
s2.x1 = 4;
s2.x2 = 7;
неверно точка s2.x1 стоит в интервале s1
s2.x1 = 5;
s2.x2 = 7
неверно точка s2x1 стоит в точке s1x2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это дополнение к этому вопросу: [Распарсить дату и сделать список диапазон дат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468668/)

Comment: И в чём ваш вопрос?

Comment: @LEQADA это более развернутый вопрос к прошлому. я просто не до конца понимаю как делать в java массив структур на примере списка. тем более как делать список вложенный в список.

Comment: Добавьте в ваш пост конкретный вопрос, иначе он довольно странно выглядит.

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev я сам путаюсь как это сказать в терминах явы. мне необходимо просто сделать как в грубо говоря си. есть структура где есть указатель на следующий элемент и еще ряд параметров начиная от Int заканчивая String. я делаю список как в ссылке которая в вопросе

Comment: Вы все пытаетесь притянуть C к Java, проблема в том, что Java по прежднему не С. Для хранения значений разного типа в Java используются коллекции объектов содержащие нужные типы, включая другие коллекции (ответ zRrr). Лучше всего полностью забыть практику С и начинать читать что то по Java - здесь принципиально другая концепция.

Comment: @pavlofff пытаюсь ...

Comment: Java - объектно-ориентированый язык в чистом виде, в отличие от процедурного С. Здесь почти все решается через объекты и манипуляции с ними и внутри них - практика С практически бесполезна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я понял пример, вы хотите список отрезков (или интервалов между двумя значениями). Для этого вам надо создать класс "Отрезок", и сделать список из объектов этого класса. В примере начало и конец отрезка - целочисленные координаты на оси X. Если нужно делать интервалы между другими типами данных, например датами, то нужны соответствующие поля этого типа плюс правки всех прочих методов.

В общем, используйте списки для одинаковых по смыслу данных. Если у вас где-то появляется группа значений одного типа, но с разным смыслом (например рост, вес и возраст - значения типа `int`) - создавайте класс.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Segments {

    public static void addIfNotIntersects( List<Segment> segments, Segment segment ) {
        for( Segment s : segments ) {
            if ( s.intersects( segment ) ) return;
        }
        segments.add( segment );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<Segment>();

        segments.add( new Segment( 2, 5 ) );

        // т.к. мы управляем тем, что добавляется в коллекцию, 
        // возможно следует создать отдельный класс для набора отрезков
        // и перенести метод addIfNotIntersects в него
        addIfNotIntersects( segments, new Segment( 6, 7 ) ); // добавится
        addIfNotIntersects( segments, new Segment( 4, 7 ) ); // не добавится


        System.out.println( segments );

        System.out.println( segments.get( 0 ) ); // первый элемент списка

        System.out.println( segments.get( 1 ).x1() ); // поле x1 второго элемента
    }
}

// класс не public, т.к. мне лень создавать отдельный файл
class Segment { // класс "Отрезок" (одномерный) с двумя точками
    private int x1, x2; // поля объявлены как private, чтобы сделать класс
                        // неизменяемым (immutable)

    // конструктор проверяет корректность входных параметров
    // и выбрасывает исключение
    public Segment( int x1, int x2 ) {
        if ( x1 > x2 ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( String.format( "Bad argument x1: %d > x2: %d", x1, x2 ) );
        }
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.x2 = x2; 
    }

    // создаем только методы чтения (геттеры, аксесоры)
    public int x1() {
        return x1;
    }

    public int x2() {
        return x2;
    }

    // метод класса проверяет пересечение этого отрезка с другим
    //   если я тут не накосячил в логике
    public boolean intersects( Segment other ) {
        return ( this.x1 <= other.x1 && other.x1 <= this.x2 )
            || ( this.x1 <= other.x2 && other.x2 <= this.x2 )
            || ( other.x2 <= this.x1 && this.x2 <= other.x2 );
    }

    // т.к. это value-класс и объекты этого класса должны поддерживать
    // эквивалентность по значению, переопределяем equals и hashCode
    // методы сгенерированы IDE, поскольку невозможно это все руками
    // делать каждый раз...
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x1;
        result = prime * result + x2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Segment other = (Segment) obj;
        if (x1 != other.x1)
            return false;
        if (x2 != other.x2)
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // возвращает строковое представление нашего объекта
    // используется в System.out.println
    // и опосредовано в List.toString() (при выводе списка)
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[" + x1 + ", " + x2 + "]";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Всё просто:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> listWithListWithList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listWithList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();

listOfIntegers.add(42);
listWithList.add(listOfIntegers);
listWithListWithList.add(listWithList);
```

Обращаться к элементам также просто:

```
int value = listWithListWithList.get(0).get(0).get(0);
System.out.println(value); //выведет 42
```