# "Список списков"

Tags: android, список

Как создать "список списков"?

Суть: пользователь жмёт на пункт меню (ListFragment) и затем открывается другой ListFragment, где также можно выбрать какой-то пункт и перейти в следующее меню и т. д. Как я понял, нужно создать класс или array.xml, где будут храниться идентификаторы ListFragment, а также их содержимое.

От чего отталкиваться?

P.S. Многоуровневый список для таких целей не подходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам может помочь конструкция вот такого [вида](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468690/17609):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> listWithListWithList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> listWithList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers = new ArrayList<>();

listOfIntegers.add(42);
listWithList.add(listOfIntegers);
listWithListWithList.add(listWithList);
```

Обращаться к элементам можно так:

```
int value = listWithListWithList.get(0).get(0).get(0);
System.out.println(value); //выведет 42
```

Соответственно вы можете сделать список списков любого уровня вложенности.

Comment: По-хорошему закрыть надо http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468690/15479

Comment: @Suvitruf, меня смущает "P.S." у ТС...\

Comment: Так зачем тогда скопировали ответ? )

Comment: @Suvitruf, возможно, ТС сам не знает чего он хочет)